# AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'point'

Tags: python, ros

I am transforming a point from source frame to target frame using [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2). Below is the code snippet:

```
import tf2_ros
import tf2_geometry_msgs

transform = tf_buffer.lookup_transform(target_frame, source_frame, rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(1.0))
pose_transformed = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_point(point_wrt_kinect, transform)
print pose_transformed
```

The code throws following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q1.py", line 29, in <module>
    pose_transformed = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_point(point_wrt_kinect, transform)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.py", line 59, in do_transform_point
    p = transform_to_kdl(transform) * PyKDL.Vector(point.point.x, point.point.y, point.point.z)
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'point'
```

The [tf_geometry_msgs.py](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_geometry_msgs) can be seen online at [here](https://github.com/mkjaergaard/geometry_experimental/blob/master/tf2_geometry_msgs/src/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.py#L60). This seems silly as they are calling `point.point.x`.

Which point are they talking about? I believe it should be [geometry_msgs/Point](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html), which I declared in the following way:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
point_wrt_kinect = Point()
point_wrt_kinect.x = -0.41
point_wrt_kinect.y = -0.13
point_wrt_kinect.z =  0.77
```

Any workaround, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do_transform_point(point_wrt_kinect, transform)

point_wrt_kinect is the object of Point class. In documentation it should be PointStamped class object. its the error of documentation.
 you have to create object of PointStamped class instead of Point class.